# C Curl 400 Bad Request keyword "on"

Tags: c, curl

I wrote a C Program that calls a webservice with cURL. I started my test by hardcoding the address of the webservice with parameters like this :
http://....php?type=adresse&texte=XYZ

It worked fine so I've tried to concatenate a variable for field texte has shown below but it failed and returned me 400 Bad Request.

We checked the content of the request and there is a keyword "on" in front of the webservice address and I don't know where that come from.

**on** http://....php?type=adresse&texte=xyz&indDebut=0&indFin=1&epsg=900913&format=json"

```
char* mystrcat( char* dest, char* src )
{
    while (*dest) dest++;
    while (*dest++ = *src++);
    return --dest;
}

recherche = "G0A3B0";
pcbak_adresse(recherche);
const char * pcbak_adresse(const char *details)
{
...
char * lien;
const char * fin_lien;

lien = "http://....php?type=adresse&texte=";
fin_lien = "&indDebut=0&indFin=1&epsg=900913&format=json";

/*Concatenation function*/
mystrcat(details, fin_lien);
mystrcat(lien, details);

/* Set CURL parameters */
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, lien);
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback_func);
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &str);

res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandler);

/* Check for errors */
if (res != CURLE_OK)
    return curl_easy_strerror(res);
...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what `mystrcat()` is,

```
mystrcat(lien, details);
```

is wrong.

- If it creates a new string composed by the two inputs, it's not being captured anywhere.
- If it tries to write to `lien` it's undefined behavior. Because you cannot modify string literals which is what `lien` is.

The same reasoning probably applies to `details`, but you didn't post `details` declaration and/or definition.

Do not use anything like `strcat()` except if you want to do it only once.

To concatenate strings use something like a structure where you store the length of the current string, the size of the target array, and of course the target array. You can then resize the target when you need to, you don't need to find the end of the target string every time (*which is what `strcat()` will do*), you also have the advantage of controlling how you append to the string with a lot of detail.

To achieve what you want, you can do this

```
char lien[256];
int length;

length = snprintf(
    lien, 
    sizeof(lien),
    "http://....php?type=adresse&texte=%s&indDebut=0&indFin=1&epsg=900913&format=json", 
    details
);
if ((length >= sizeof(lien)) || (length == -1))
    return error_occurred_here();
```

Also, returning a static string (*which probably is what `curl_easy_strerror()` returns*), and a tentatively dynamic one from the same function is bad design, because,

1. You can't tell whether it's an error or the JSON returned from the link.
2. You will need some method to determine whether it's a static string or the one generated in the function in order to `free()` it.

Comment: I've added some informations to improve comprehension of my code. The result from my concatenation is what I expected a working http address that I can paste in a browser and it works fine. Thanks for your help, i'll review my code.

Comment: @batroc The result of your code is undefined behavior, you may think it's working but not necessarily. Follow my advice and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I use snprintf now and it works perfectly.